# Android override methods when user returns to the app

Tags: android

Hi i'm trying to create a popup that pops up when the user leaves/returns to the app. for example a phone call comes in and they want to go back to app i want the popup to display then. which override methods do i need to make this work?

Comment: Why would a *user* want this?

Comment: @CommonsWare it's not an advert it's a pin number entry form for the users security essentially the app contains personal data for the user and in which the user sets a pin number at the start i'm wanting to add this so that the user must enter pin to access the page when returning to the app. just for the users security

Comment: Then the issue is not when the user returns to the app, but when the user has not used the app for X period of time, so their authentication credentials have expired. Pestering the user with an authentication dialog just because they left your app for a couple of seconds will make you very unpopular.

Comment: @CommonsWare Not necessarily. I've downloaded the app Vaulty, which does what he's saying he wants to do. I don't find it annoying.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the lifecycles of [Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) or [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), depending on your needs.

You will probably need `onResume()` or `onRestart()`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

Use `onResume()` and/or `onRestart()`. Both of these methods will run when the application is brought back up after being hidden (taking a phone call, closing the app but not destroying it, etc.), but the `onResume()` method will run on start up of the application, whereas `onRestart()` will not.

```
// this method will run when the app is first started as well
public void onResume()
{
     super.onResume();
     // put your popup here 
}

public void onRestart()
{
     super.onRestart();
     // put your popup here
}
```

---

#### Sources:

[Stopping and Restarting an Activity | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html)
[Activity | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

---

#### Tip:

I suggest displaying a [Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) in each of the methods telling you which method you're in, so that you can test when each method is being executed.

Example:

```
public void onResume()
{
     super.onResume();
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onResume()", 0).show();
}

public void onRestart()
{
     super.onRestart();
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onRestart()", 0).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try [onUserLeaveHint()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint%28%29), [onUserInteraction()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction%28%29) and look in the direction of `BroadcastReceivers`